# ArcMap / ArcObjects - Type "OLEDBWorkspaceFactory" is not defined when creating a new workspace

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcobjects, vb.net

Making an Add-In for ArcMap, refactoring old VBA code into VB.NET.
Trying to create a new workspace with ArcObjects in VB.NET.

I am getting the error:

> BC30002 Type "OLEDBWorkspaceFactory" is not defined

I tried this example [IWorkspaceFactory2 Example](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/arcobjects/esriGeoDatabase/IWorkspaceFactory2_Example.htm), but I was also getting the same error with **SdeWorkspaceFactory** not being defined.

Below is how the code looks like. How would you rewrite it to work?

```
Dim pWorkspaceFact As IWorkspaceFactory2
pWorkspaceFact = New OLEDBWorkspaceFactory

Dim pWorkspace As IWorkspace
pWorkspace = pWorkspaceFact.Open(pPropSet, 0)

Dim pEnumDatasetNames As IEnumDatasetName
pEnumDatasetNames = pWorkspace.DatasetNames(esriDTTable)
```

Comment: Is this a standalone exe?  If so, if you don't initialize (checkout) an Esri license, trying to create a workspace object can throw an exception.

Comment: It's an add-in for ArcMap, so I'm trying to make a custom button. Do I need to initiliaze an Esri License for an add-in?

Answer (score 2):

This code works, I just made a typo blunder! It was a small typo in my namespace that I referenced in.

I wrote

```
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.DatasourcesOledDB
```

When it should have been

```
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesOleDB
```